# PHP laravel sortBy to orderBy

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have following code, which basically gets the result of the query in Descending Order for episodeNumber (many) which is inside relationship model (one to many) of `TheNumbers`.

```
$nearEpisodes = TheEpisode::where("seriesID", $seriesID)->get()->sortByDesc(function ($item) {
    return $item->TheNumbers->max('episodeNumber');
})->values();
```

Can I do same thing, without using `sortByDesc`, and instead use `orderBy` for better performance?

This will allow me to paginate it after.

Comment: TheEpisode::where("seriesID", $seriesID)       ->orderBy('episodeNumber', 'desc') .   ->get();            try this one...

Comment: `episodeNumber` is inside `TheNumbers`, it doesn't exist inside `TheEpisode`

Comment: in the relationship function (TheEpisode model), do the orderBy() for episodeNumber.

Comment: I dont need to order the TheNumbers, I need to order TheEpisodes

Comment: Then try this, TheEpisode::where("seriesID", $seriesID) ->orderBy('id', 'desc') . ->get();

Comment: I dont need to order by `id` I need to order by TheNumbers.episodeNumber

Comment: Can your show your table schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about how your tables are linked but you can use `join` to paginate the model as:

```
TheEpisode::where("seriesID", $seriesID)
        ->join('TheNumbers', 'seriesID.id', '=', 'TheNumbers.TheEpisode_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('TheEpisode.*, MAX(episodeNumber) as `max_episodeNumber`'))
        ->groupBy('TheEpisode_id')
        ->orderBy('max_episodeNumber', 'desc')
        ->paginate(10);
```